# Umbraco 8 IUmbracoEntity AdditionalData

Tags: umbraco, umbraco8

In Umbraco v7 `IUmbracoEntity` used to have a property called [AdditionalData](https://our.umbraco.com/apidocs/v7/csharp/api/Umbraco.Core.Models.EntityBase.IUmbracoEntity.html#Umbraco_Core_Models_EntityBase_IUmbracoEntity_AdditionalData) which doesn't exist anymore in v8. I can't find any documentation on this dictionary or where it's stored in the db or whether it's migrated in v8 or not?

Is there any alternatives? and how to migrate the old AdditionalData dictionary to the new alternative?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/ the [IHaveAdditionalData](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/v8/contrib/src/Umbraco.Core/Models/Entities/IHaveAdditionalData.cs) interface is implemented on Members, MemberGroups *and* if we go down the rabbit hole [IEntitySlim](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/v8/contrib/src/Umbraco.Core/Models/Entities/IEntitySlim.cs) which also happens to implement IUmbracoEntity.

Does that help you? I'm not sure... But maybe if you have a chance to use IEntitySlim where you used to use IUmbracoEntity, you'll have the same properties (ish) as you did in v7?

Comment: Indeed it exists on `IEntitySlim` and you can retrieve it from `IEntityService` but it's read only as the `EntityService` doesn't allow to save the entity back

Comment: Hm. Maybe I'd be better equipped to help if you shared a bit more of the context? What are you trying to do? :-)

Comment: I am trying to save some additional data on an `IContent` during the Saving event then retreive it later during the publishing event.